# A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Muscle>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a custom Muscle Class:

```
class Muscle {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Muscle({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

I'm using a package named multi_select_flutter and I'm running into a problem assigning here from values to _selectedMuscles:

```
MultiSelectChipField(
                        items: _items,
                        initialValue: _muscles,
                        title: Text("Select Muscles"),
                        headerColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.8),
                        ),
                        selectedChipColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                        selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                        onTap: (values) {
                          _selectedMuscles = values;
                        },
                      ),
```

The full error I get is:

```
A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Muscle>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Muscle>'
```

I have tried casting using:
 `_selectedMuscles = (List<Muscle>)values;` but that doesn't work. Any ideas on how I can cast?

Comment: Where did you declared the _selectedMuscles ? it should be List<Muscle?> _selectedMuscles;

Comment: Or try                           _selectedMuscles = values ?? List<Muscle?>[];

Comment: @RehamAlraee I tried that change and I get `A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Muscle?>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Muscle?>'` and I also get `The name of the class 'List' can't be included in a list literal.
Try removing 'List'`

Answer (score 2):

Where did you define `_items` and `_muscles`? What types are they? Did you maybe forget to properly type them and one of them is just a `List` instead of a proper type like `List<Muscle>`?

Anyway, you can always override the automatic inference of the type argument and do it yourself:

```
MultiSelectChipField<Muscle>(
```

Then you will probably get compiler errors telling you where you missed the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
List<Object?> _items = ....;
List<Muscle> muscleList = _items.map((e)=>Muscle(e)).toList();
```